# datetime.TryParseExact with different formats of values

Tags: c#

I have a json string that contains the values for a datetime and a parsing mechanism that looks like this:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(TheUserTimeString, "M.d.yyyy.HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out TheUserTime))
 {
    TheObject.UserDateTime = TheUserTime;
 }
```

The string TheUserTimeString is generated on the client. It can be `12.20.2011.13.21` and the code works fine but when it's `12.20.2011.13.2` the code breaks because the minutes are in one digit. And when the month is also in one digit... who knows.

What would be a better way to rewrite this parsing code so that the string gets parsed correctly every time.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: could you change the M.d.yyy.HH.m" to be of a string.format and that way..? or perhaps add MM.dd otherwise sounds like you will have to do a check if the Mins in terms of lengh is < 2 1-9 should fail ...is that a correct assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the string `"M.d.yyyy.HH.m"`, a single `m` denotes minutes without the leading 0. [Source](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Comment: ok, will this also work when the values are in two digit formats like 12 for December?

Comment: Yes, both cases (one digit and two digits for minutes) will work, and so will month numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your DateTime format string just needs to be: `"M.d.yyyy.H.m"`.
This allows for months, days, hours and minutes to be expressed as single digit values.

See [here for the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) documenting the valid formats of this string for further information.